# Markup ending without empty line. But markup is only thing in comment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

When documenting my python code I have a decorator to mark functions deprecated that also updates the docstring. This works fine if the function has documentation but when it doesn't sphinx complains and the documentation for `deprecated` does not look correct.

I have narrowed the problem down to the equivalent code:

```
def func():
    """.. deprecated:: 0.1.0
  Please use :func:`func_new`

    """
```

These are all variations I have tried without success:

```
def func():
    """.. deprecated:: 0.1.0
    Please use :func:`func_new`

    """

def func():
    """
    .. deprecated:: 0.1.0
        Please use :func:`func_new`

    """
```

In this case Sphinx complains with `WARNING: Explicit markup ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.`. It does not matter how many empty lines I have at the end or if the lines have some spaces in front of it.

I would not care about the warning if the documentation was ok but instead of producing

```
Module.func():
    Deprecated since version 0.1.0: Please use :func:`func_new`
```

the output is

```
Module.func():
    Deprecated since version 0.1.0.

    Please use :func:`func_new`
```

How can I fix this without having to add any (visible) text to the docstring?

Comment: Is the problem here not that the second line is only indented two spaces, which throws off the dedenting for the whole docstring? What happens if it's indented a further two spaces (i.e. before `Please`)? Do you think this is a problem in Sphinx, or in the decorator (which you haven't actually shown)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated the question with more examples. I have not posted the decorator as it is irrelevant as the created docstring is exactly thesame as i have posted. The docstring is being modified correctly ( I can see the changes in the created documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jonrsharpe pointed me to the right direction with the dedent.

The documentation string must be exactly like this:

```
def func():
    """
    .. deprecated:: 0.1.0
      Please use :func:`func_new`

    """
```

Two spaces in the next line, and `.. deprecated` must be aligned with the starting `"""` block. It cannot start in the same line as the `"""`.

Dedenting the docstring and adding a `\n` before `.. deprecated` fixed my problem.